# Enable drag-drop functionality in ng-tree angular 1.2

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to enable drag-drop functionality in tree view of angular 1.2 only , currently I am using ng-tree directive , I have checked in Angular Api there I have not found such control for tree sample code is below

```
<ul ng-tree="leftTree.children" ng-hide='treeLoading'>
            <li ng-show="$parent.item.expanded || !$parent.item"
                ng-class="{active: item.id == selectedObj.id}" id="item_{{item.id}}">
                <div>
                    <i class="pull-left" ng-class="{'icon-gt-collapse': item.expanded && !item.leaf && !item.loading, 'icon-gt-expand': ((!item.expanded && !item.leaf) || item.showPlusIcon) && !item.loading, 'icon-spinner': item.loading, 'icon-spin': item.loading }" ng-click="toggleCollapse(item)"></i> 
                    <a ng-click="getItemInfo(item)"  style="font-size:0.85em;"><i ng-class="{'icon-list-alt': item.leaf, 'icon-folder-close': !item.expanded && !item.leaf, 'icon-folder-open': item.expanded && !item.leaf }"></i> <span ng-show="item.id > 0">{{item.description}}</span><span ng-show="item.id == 0">New Component</span></a>
                </div>
            </li>
```

apart from ordering I want to change the children parents also with simple drag. Any ideas ?